# dispatch_async memory problems in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, grand-central-dispatch

I have a loop of about 2000+ items I need to go through:

```
for (NSDictionary* dict in array) {

                NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@_lg.jpg?t=",manufacturerID, [[dict valueForKey:@"ItemID"]  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"%20"]];
                NSString *savePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
                NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [[NSString stringWithFormat:kProductImagesURL, fileName]stringByAppendingString:lastImagesSyncDate]];

                dispatch_queue_t aQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0);
                dispatch_async(aQueue, ^{

                    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
                    [request startSynchronous];
                    NSError *error = [request error];
                    if (!error) {
                        int statusCode = [request responseStatusCode];
                        if (statusCode==200) {
                            NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
                            [responseData writeToFile:[savePath stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%20" withString:@" "] atomically:YES];
                        }  
                    }
                });
            }
```

This works great and my main thread is not blocked but my memory goes through the roof - how do I get it to be released?  Once the queue is empty it drops but I need it to clear out as it is going along.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although you are running the code in the background you are running **all** of the code in the background at the same time. As fast you are able to loop through the array you are creating a new ASIHttpRequest that will be trying to download and save data at the same time. You may want to move your loop inside of the `dispatch_async`, or use an [`NSOperation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html) that does the same thing but limit the max concurrent operations on the [`NSOperationQueue`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html). If you move the loop inside of `dispatch_async` to do one at a time remember to create an [`NSAutoreleasePool`](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSAutoreleasePool) locally and drain it periodically.

Comment: Or use a semaphore to control the # of simultaneous operations.

Comment: I ended up just putting an NSAutoReleasePool around the ASIHTTPRequest bit and it worked like a charm - part of my problem was I was not building for profiler every time so I was making changes and not seeing a difference - frustratingly stupid thing to forget

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of getting an autoreleased `ASIHTTPRequest` , try to alloc ,init , release one.
2. Haven't tried it , but think about alternating async and sync calls (to the same thread, not the main one)  , like having 20 async requests followed by one sync.. this trick could help.